# Add and read Multiple textboxes

Tags: c#, winforms

What is the best way to create and read multiple textboxes in a windows form? In my application, I have a windows form where customer can enter multiple addresses, email addresses

Right now I have a form like this,

```
TextBoxAddress1  TextBoxEmail1
TextBoxAddress2  TextBoxEmail2
.....
.....
.....
TextBoxAddressN  TextBoxEmailN
```

For this I dragged and dropped multiple controls on a form and named each one of them.

If I use this method I had to write lengthy code to see if first row (TextBoxAddress1  TextBoxEmail1) is filled for validation and even for reading I had to write many lines of code.

Is there a better to way achieve this?

Comment: Not clear what you're asking, atleast for me.

Comment: Are you talking about validating the control and popping up a messagebox if invalid?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following code to add a `TextBox` dynamically to your form:

```
private int m_CurrTexboxYPos = 10;
private List<TextBox> m_TextBoxList = new List<TextBox>();

private void CreateCheckBox()
{
    m_CurrTexboxYPos += 25;
    TextBox textbox = new TextBox();
    textbox.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, m_CurrTexboxYPos);
    textbox.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(100,20);
    Controls.Add(textbox);
    m_TextBoxList.Add(textbox);
}
```

Comment: Just added line `Controls.Add(textbox);` which I omitted.

Answer (score 1):

I would have a listbox/listview with your emails and Add/Edit/Delete buttons which show a popup form - the logic for validating emails, etc. would then be in the one place and your list can grow without you ever needing to add controls to the form.

You could dynamically create textboxes - but you end up writing code to make sure they layout nicely on the form, etc. - having some type of list is easier IMO and also lends itself to binding (e.g. to an email object)

Comment: And since OP was asking how to read these email address they can just call:  `listBox1.Controls.AsQueryable().Where(x => x is TextBox)` then easily process each textbox in a `foreach` loop.

Answer (score 1):

Dynamically adding controls is pretty simple, provided you can use `DockStyle` and an exclusive container for them (e.g. a `Panel`). If you can't use `DockStyle`, then you need to write logic to determine `Location` and `Size` (which isn't fun).

On a simple form, I have two buttons and a panel, `Button1` adds a new `TextBox` to `Panel1`, `Button2` iterates through the controls in `Panel1` and then checks that they are the correct type or throws an exception. This is where you you would put validation or reading logic. Panel1 needs to have `AutoScroll = true;` otherwise you will run controls off of the viewable screen.

This concept can be switched for anything that inherits from `UserControl` (all .Net native controls or your own custom controls).

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox NewEmailBox = new TextBox();
    NewEmailBox.Name = "NewEmailBox" + this.panel1.Controls.Count;
    NewEmailBox.Dock = DockStyle.Top;
    this.panel1.Controls.Add(NewEmailBox);

}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (Control item in this.panel1.Controls)
    {
        if (item is TextBox)
        {
            //Do your reading/validating here.
        }
        else
        {
            throw new InvalidCastException(string.Format("{0} was in Panel1 and is of type {1} not TextBox!", item.Name, item.GetType()));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Write a user control for each of the groupings you need. at least one One for address, one for email etc.  then all of your validation, calls to your database access is contained in a single location

That is just good design.  this way if you have multiple tabs for things like Home Information, Work Information, Emergency Contact Information, you can just place them on the form. This is pretty common for a user profile.

Then a listview for each grouping on a user profile page or whatever, that has edit/delete/add then popup a dialog with the appropriate user control in it.

Answer (score 0):

Most simply, ListBox adove TextBox with Button.

[image: 1.]

Also you can use DataGridView, BuiltIn functionality for Add\Edit\Delete.

Here using DataGridView (ShowHeader set to false, `EditMode` to `On Enter`, with one Column with `AutoSizeMode` in  `Fill` property)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The less of repeatable code you have, the better programmer you are.

Whenever you see a *pattern* (something what is repeatable), you could and you should try to optimize it. Unless it's something too small to worry.

In your case, determine first what is the basic of repeatable thing. Do you always have to enter address and email address? Then combine them into a control, which can carry out validation. Do you have to use this control often (or repeat N times)? Then maybe it make sense to switch to a list instead (`ListBox`, `ListView` or `DataGridView`).

Are you *too lazy* to bother configuring things? Then just optimize something what is obviously going to repeat: put validation into common method and call it from each `TextBox` event. Or make own `TextBox` with method build-in. Or do validation at once in the `Ok` button event by using loop.. or not by using loop.

To find *best* method you have to first decide best for who. Because customer want something shiny,easy to use, animated, with cats and boobs.. ok, without cats and boobs. The point is: how much work are you willing to put to have it *best for the customer*.

If I would have to enter *table* data (or data which form table), I'd go with `DataGridView` so it would looks like this.. or better:

[image]